# Firebase sort children by the time added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I sort my Firebase children by the date I added each child? I want the first child added to be the first, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `date` field in your database:

```
Users
 pushid
  name: userx
  date: 2018-03-04
  email: userx@gmail.com
 pushid
  name: usery
  date: 2018-03-06
  email: usery@gmail.com
```

then you can do this:

```
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
ref.orderByChild("date").startAt("2018-03-04").endAt("2018-03-06");
```